# Does the BadUSB issue also affect SD cards?

Tags: usb, sd-card

Since I've heard about the [BadUSB issue](https://srlabs.de/badusb/) where the firmware of a USB stick can be maliciously changed, I was thinking about ways to avoid this issue.

Would using SD cards as an alternative to USB sticks (given that all computers I use have card readers) avoid this issue?

I realize that these card readers would still be susceptible to hardware destruction but I am more concerned about software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To a point, it's safer. But sd cards are turning more into usb everyday.

Sd cards will still be vulnerable to having viruses on them, and a user clicking on the program to launch them. I don't see them being used as hid (human interface devices) yet, so you should be safe in that regard.

Having said that, what is your potential attack vector? Are you sharing the sd cards or usb flash drives with other people (strangers or known people, alike)? If you are the sole user and will maintain complete control of the flash drives, then I would not worry about it.

Comment: My idea is that some people might want to share a few files with me and hand me a USB stick. Or I would use my own USB sticks at other people's machines or even public computers like in a copy shop. I don't want to buy a new USB stick every time, I go to those places. Viruses and alike would be avoided with other measures. So basically, I wouldn't give it away completely, but it might get "infected" while I use it at someone's machine.

Comment: once it leaves your hands, you can't guarantee it isn't infected. Using a couple good anti viruses, before it comes to your real machine, will be the best, most paranoid course of action, if you share it